# Magento 2 How to check if Admin Logged on frontend

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

I'm trying to check if admin is logged in on frontend in Magento 2 but I didn't find the way.

Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My source below may some helpful.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="name_of_observer_for_backend_auth_user_login_success" instance="\Instance\Class\Name" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create the observer.

```
class BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND = 'PHPSESSID';

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute()
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if (! isset($_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND])) return;
        $backSessionId = session_id();
        $frontendSessionId = $_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($frontendSessionId);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['admin'] = [$backSessionId];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($backSessionId);
        session_start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Now after admin login then you can get admin session id by front-end session in `$_SESSION['admin']`, and you can use `session_id($_SESSION['admin'][0])` switch session details and continue.

This code need front-end session id already created, so must add one iframe `(src=frontend.anypage)` to `backend/auth/login` page.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

Every backend action controller have access to the `$this->_auth` variable which is an instance of `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth` declared in the constructor of `Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction`.

To check if an admin user is logged in you can use:

```
$this->_auth->isLoggedIn()
```

In your controller.

In case you're not working with a controller you can use Dependency Injection in your constructor:

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
) {
    $this->_session = $authSession;

    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

And then call:

```
$this->_session->isLoggedIn()
```

Comment: @JuanPBarba my bad misread

Comment: @JuanPBarba see my edit ;)

Comment: Thank you @RaphaelatDigitalPianism but I have tried this method and it gives me always false... 
I'm looking for checking if ADMIN logged on FRONTEND

Comment: Well that's an interesting one, I reckon you should see with Alan Storm if he made an M2 version of his module: https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions/

Comment: Ok, I will ^^  Thank you again @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: @JuanPBarba Have you solved that issue? can you detail?

Comment: As other commentors have said, this just returns false all the time.

Comment: working fine...