# Magento 2 How to check on front-end side if admin is logged-in or not

Tags: magento2, admin, session

The below code works in Magento 1.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
if ($adminSession->isLoggedIn()) {
  $adminIpAddress = $adminSession['_session_validator_data']['remote_addr'];
}
```

I am trying below code in magento 2 that is working in admin section but not working on front end

```
 $adminSession= $this->auth->isLoggedIn();
    including (\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth)
```

**I need to check if admin is logged in or not on front end in magento2**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My source below may some helpful.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="name_of_observer_for_backend_auth_user_login_success" instance="\Instance\Class\Name" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create the observer.

```
class BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND = 'PHPSESSID';

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute()
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if (! isset($_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND])) return;
        $backSessionId = session_id();
        $frontendSessionId = $_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($frontendSessionId);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['admin'] = [$backSessionId];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($backSessionId);
        session_start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Now after admin login then you can get admin session id by front-end session in `$_SESSION['admin']`, and you can use `session_id($_SESSION['admin'][0])` switch session details and continue.

This code need front-end session id already created, so must add one iframe `(src=frontend.anypage)` to `backend/auth/login` page.

Source :
[Magento 2 How to check if Admin Logged on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106631/magento-2-how-to-check-if-admin-logged-on-frontend)
Check for more details.

There is answer exactly for your problem ;)

Comment: I've tried this.It's not working as I want.Session is being created and saved when admin logged in but how to get on front-end and if admin logout then what will happen.This above code is just creating and saving session when admin login.

Comment: @PriyankaGarg have you found any solution?