# Magento 2: Get Admin session in frontend

Tags: magento2, admin, session

How can i get the admin session in frontend.

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $adminSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager');
   print_r($adminSession->getCurrentSession()->getStatus());
```

I tried with above script but no luck!

Comment: Maybe you can check this related topic.
[Magento 2 How to check if Admin Logged on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106631/magento-2-how-to-check-if-admin-logged-on-frontend)

Comment: What you actually want to do ?

Comment: If you can provide more details about your goal, I can try to advise with solution. You should understand that `admin` cookie writes (and allows) only to your backend path and you cannot get it in code on frontend. Possible to create additional cookie in admin for frontend and work with it, but anyway need to understand a goal, maybe possible to implement more nicely solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Here you want to get admin session data into the frontend. Both areas are different so we can not get admin current admin login session. For more about area [click here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/architecture/modules/areas/#area-types). I give you the solution for it.**

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_admin_user" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Admin Active USER">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="admin_id" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Admin ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="status" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Admin Active Status"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="checkout_time" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" comment="Admin Checkout Time"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**ActiveAdminData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveAdminData as ActiveAdminDataResourceModel;

class ActiveAdminData extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(ActiveAdminDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

**ActiveAdminData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class ActiveAdminData extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_admin_user', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/ActiveAdminData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveAdminData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ActiveAdminData as ActiveAdminDataModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ActiveAdminData as ActiveAdminDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            ActiveAdminDataModel::class,
            ActiveAdminDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="custom_admin_session_status" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\GetActiveAdminStatus" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**GetActiveAdminStatus.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class GetActiveAdminStatus implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $authSession;
    protected $state;
    protected $getActiveAdmin;
    protected $userFactory;
    protected $registry;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ActiveAdminDataFactory $getActiveAdmin,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->getActiveAdmin = $getActiveAdmin;
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $areaCode = $this->state->getAreaCode();
        /* Get active admin user */
        if ($areaCode == "frontend") {
            $activeAdmin = [];
            $activeUserData = $this->getActiveAdmin->create()->getCollection();
            $activeUserData->addFieldToFilter('status', '1');
            if ($activeUserData->count()) {
                foreach ($activeUserData as $activeUserKey => $activeUserVal) {
                    $adminData = $this->userFactory->create()->load($activeUserVal->getAdminId());
                    if ($adminData->hasData()) {
                        $activeAdmin[] = $adminData->toArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->registry->register('active_admins', $activeAdmin);
        }
        /* Set active admin user */
        if ($areaCode == "adminhtml") {
            $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
            if ($fullActionName != "adminhtml_auth_logout") {
                $AdminloginStatus = $this->authSession->isLoggedIn();
                if ($AdminloginStatus) {
                    $inActiveTime = 120;
                    $adminId = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId();
                    $activeUserData = $this->getActiveAdmin->create()->getCollection();
                    $activeUserData->addFieldToFilter('admin_id', $adminId);
                    // print_r($activeUserData->getData());
                    if ($activeUserData->count()) {
                        /* Update active admin user */
                        $activeUserData = $activeUserData->getFirstItem();
                        $activeUserData->setStatus('1');
                        $activeUserData->setCheckoutTime($inActiveTime);
                        $activeUserData->save();
                    } else {
                        /* Add new admin user */
                        $setActiveUser = $this->getActiveAdmin->create();
                        $setActiveUser->setAdminId($adminId);
                        $setActiveUser->setStatus('1');
                        $setActiveUser->setCheckoutTime($inActiveTime);
                        $setActiveUser->save();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /* Logout admin user */
                $adminId = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId();
                $activeUserData = $this->getActiveAdmin->create()->getCollection();
                $activeUserData->addFieldToFilter('admin_id', $adminId);
                if ($activeUserData->count()) {
                    $activeUserData = $activeUserData->getFirstItem();
                    $activeUserData->setStatus('0');
                    $activeUserData->setCheckoutTime(0);
                    $activeUserData->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Cron\SetAdminStatus" method="execute" name="custom_admin_status">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Cron**

**SetAdminStatus.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Cron;

class SetAdminStatus
{
    protected $getActiveAdmin;

    public function __construct(
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ActiveAdminDataFactory $getActiveAdmin
    ) {
        $this->getActiveAdmin = $getActiveAdmin;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $activeUserData = $this->getActiveAdmin->create()->getCollection();
        $activeUserData->addFieldToFilter('status', '1');
        foreach ($activeUserData as $activeUserKey => $activeUserVal) {
            $checkoutTime = intval($activeUserVal->getCheckoutTime() - 1);
            if ($checkoutTime <= 0) {
                $activeUserVal->setCheckoutTime('0');
                $activeUserVal->setStatus('0');
            } else {
                $activeUserVal->setCheckoutTime($checkoutTime);
            }
            $activeUserVal->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\GetActiveAdmins" name="get.active.admin" before="-" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::adminlist.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**GetActiveAdmins.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

class GetActiveAdmins extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getActiveAdmin()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('active_admins');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**adminlist.phtml**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
echo "<br>Call From Helper<br>";
$helperClass = $this->helper(\VendoreName\ModuleName\Helper\Data::class);
print_r($helperClass->getActiveAdmin());
echo "<br>Call From Block<br>";
print_r($block->getActiveAdmin());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Helper**

**Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getActiveAdmin()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('active_admins');
    }
}
```

**When the admin is login then its status is going to active and if he/she sign out then its status goes to inactive. and also if the admin user is login and does not have any activity by admin then its status goes to inactive. In the Observer GetActiveAdminStatus.php file you can set your time what you want**

Comment: how can I get the user session on the frontend if I'm logged in and have access to the admin cookie for the admin user?

Something like ```$user = $this->backendUserModel->getById or getBySessionId()

I want the data equivalent to like what you get here for "user" if using the event vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:169 ```['user' => $this->getCredentialStorage()]

Comment: @KevinChavez you can store admin cookie data in the custom_admin_user table by adding a new column. and get them in the front end by using the above code.

Comment: @KevinChavez you can also add your data into https://nimb.ws/vh6ayo array and get them using Registry. Data must be store into our table.

Answer (score 1):

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="name_of_observer_for_backend_auth_user_login_success" instance="\Instance\Class\Name" />
    </event>
```

Then create the observer.

```
class BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND = 'PHPSESSID';

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute()
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if (! isset($_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND])) return;
        $backSessionId = session_id();
        $frontendSessionId = $_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($frontendSessionId);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['admin'] = [$backSessionId];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($backSessionId);
        session_start();
        return;
    }
}
</config>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
protected $_session;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
) {
    $this->_session = $authSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

and then call

```
$this->_session->isLoggedIn()
```

**Note:** don't use `objectManager` directly in the code. Its not proper way to do it in Magento 2.

Comment: no luck and \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context instead of \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,

Comment: Does this work? When I try this from frontend controller isLoggedIn returns false, I'm guessing it's because frontend has different session

Comment: no current answer does not work