# how to check admin loggedin or not on frontend magento 2

Tags: admin, adminhtml, admin-panel, adminform, admin-controller

how to check admin loggedIn or not on front-end magento 2 .I have tried this

```
class BackendAuthUserLoginSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    const DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND = 'PHPSESSID';

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface::execute()
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if (! isset($_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND])) return;
        $backSessionId = session_id();
        $frontendSessionId = $_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_NAME_OF_FRONTEND];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($frontendSessionId);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['admin'] = [$backSessionId];
        session_write_close();
        session_id($backSessionId);
        session_start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of the below mentioned question, it's already answered

[Magento 2 How to check if Admin Logged on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106631/magento-2-how-to-check-if-admin-logged-on-frontend)