# check admin loggedIn on frontend magento 2

Tags: admin, adminhtml, admin-panel, admin-controller, admin-login

i have tried through this method

```
public function isAdmin() {
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        echo $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
        echo 'session test4';
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106631/magento-2-how-to-check-if-admin-logged-on-frontend

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected $_session;
 public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
) { $this->_session = $authSession;
   parent::__construct($context);
 }
```

Use:-

`$this->_session->isLoggedIn()`

to check whether the admin is logged in or not.